# linear transformation of some matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be $n \times 2$, and $\Omega$ be $2 \times 2$ matrices, respectively, and define $A=F\Omega F'$. I want to get a representation as follows

$A=F\Omega F'=HH'$

where 
\begin{equation}
H=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
h_{11} & 0 \\ 
h_{21} & h_{22} \\ 
h_{31} & h_{32} \\ 
h_{41} & h_{42}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

I want to know how I can get $H$ by applying linear transformations to $F$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: I guess $F'$ denotes the transpose of $F$. Then $\Omega$ should probably be symmetric.

Comment: Sorry for not defining precisely. Yes, " ' " denotes the transpose and $\Omega$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: Is $n$ equal to 4 as your $H$ is suggesting?

Comment: Yes, $n=4$. The point is that (1,2) element of $H$ is $0$.